# Using gpg to sign an RPM as part of a continous build - how do I avoid the prompt for the passphrase?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, signing, gnupg

I have a continuous integration build system that generates an RPM via a shell script triggered by cron. I want to sign the RPM with gpg, but gpg insists on the user manually entering the passphrase at the console, which is clearly a non-starter since there is no user console for cron.

I have read about gpg-agent which will let you enter the passphrase once for the current login session, but again cron does not have a login session.  What I would like is to be able to configure gpg-agent to accept the passphrase once at boot time and hand that to the cron session when needed.  I have no idea if this is possible or not, and the docs for gpg-agent are fairly minimal.

The alternative would be to use expect to enter the passphrase when gpg asks for it, but clearly this is a big security hole since the passphrase will need to be included in the build script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start gpg-agent at start up and save the GPG_AGENT_INFO environment variable. Then you can set it up in your script's environment and should work as expected. Additionally, make sure permissions of the socket in GPG_AGENT_INFO allow your script to read it.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am looking for.  But how do you query or set the permissions on a socket?

Comment: You set the permission as usual (chown on the path in GPG_AGENT_INFO). Then, if the environment variable is set, gpg should use it with no more action on your side. Note that I haven't tried this case, so let's see if it works ;)

Answer (score -1):

Whatever build tool you use to generate the RPM could have the capability to sign it.  For example, gradle has a plugin that does the signing for you.  You have to create a properties file with the id, passphrase, and location of the key ring file, and it does the rest.

See:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.